# How resize proportionally a div inside a bootstrap grid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

despite I'm reading so many online sources I still struggling fully understand the css/html box model. In particular I'm trying to create some section that have a proportion of 3*2, where 3 is the width and 2 the height. [image: section]

I've tried in vain using the scss variables:

```
.boxProject{
  width: 90%;
  height: calc((width/3) *2);
  background: purple;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Also, the Bootstrap grid has no sense at all to me, cause if I insert the `h-100` class, then the grid overflow it's div container, and I haven't found yet a way to make the div 'resizable' specially on smaller screen where the contents are displayed one below the other resulting in a narrow width but in a long height.

```css
.projectSection{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#section4 h1 {
  margin:auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #62daf5, #59c8f4, #52aef9, #4586f7);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.boxProject{
  width: 90%;
  height: calc((width/3) *2);
  background: purple;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#section4{
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="section4">

        <div class="row mt-5">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1> My Projects. </h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row h-75 w-100 mt-4">
            <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                <div class="boxProject"> </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                <div class="boxProject"> </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                <div class="boxProject"> </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                <div class="boxProject"> </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                <div class="boxProject"> </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                <div class="boxProject"> </div>
            </div>

        </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you declare `width` as a SCSS variable, you can't use `width` as part of the calc. Instead, you could do something like this: `calc((90vw/3) * 2)`, where 90vw is essentially 90% of the viewport width. To use it as a variable:

```
// declare the variable
$width: '90vw';

// style block 
.boxProject {
    width: 90%;
    height: calc((#{$width} / 3) * 2); // note the variable is declared inside #${}
    background: purple;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap works with breakpoints meaning when your display is smaller than i.e. `1200px` the grid is downsized to `large screens`.
So resizing has nothing to do with bootstrap. However, if you want to resize a `div` you can simply add this css snippet:

```html
.resizable {
     resize: vertical;
     overflow: auto; /* Or hidden */
}
```

This should also work with `col`'s

See codepen here: https://codepen.io/Throvn/pen/OJJGExy